# How to get DataContext from hit test method on listView column C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, events, hittest

I try to determine which column's header have been clicked on my listView.

For that I have been added event method previewMouseLeftButtonUp.

```
<ListView x:Name="offers_listView"  Margin="10,10,10,227" Height="500" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="offers_listView_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp">
```

which have implementation as below:

```
    private void offers_listView_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var point = Mouse.GetPosition(offers_listView);

        var hit = offers_listView.InputHitTest(point);

        offers_listView.IsHitTestVisible = true;


        //if(hit.DataContext == "")
        //{

        //}

    }
```

So what I would like to expect is name of column and in debug mode I have found it:

[image]

The problem is that in coding mode I can't get property DataContext as you may observe on below screen:

[image]

My question is how I can get this info another way or how I may activate DataContext property to be useful in this moment ?

Thanks in advance, regards

Comment: Did you try casting it to a listviewitem and then get its `DataContext` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hit` is derived from `FrameworkElement` because its the `UIElement` that was hit, the debugger recognizes it. if you want to access the property `DataContext` you have to cast `hit` to `FrameWorkElement`.

Example:

```
object dataContext = (hit as FrameworkElement).DataContext;
```